# Does the likelihood of spontaneous labour increase with every membrane sweep?

Tags: birth, obstetrics

Two  or three membrane sweeps are offered to overdue mothers in weeks 40 and 41 to start labour. Is it advisable to skip the first membrane sweep at week 40 and simply wait for a week, or does this decrease the probability of “spontaneous labour”, therefore leading to a higher chance of other means of induction?

---

Most of the literature I found looks at the efficacy of sweeps (vs. no sweep at all). They find that yes, sweeps are useful for bringing on labour.

[Dutch study utilising repeated membrane sweeps](https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1471-0528.2006.00870.x)

[Cochrane Review](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD000451.pub2/full)

But I did find an [RCT](https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1471-0528.1998.tb09348.x) that indicated that 40-week sweeps increased the effectiveness of 41-week sweeps:

> one week later (at 39 weeks). However, nulliparous women had previously seemed to benefit most from sweeping of the membrane.
>   We think that weekly sweeping puts women in a pre-labour situation where irregular contractions have a cervical ripening effect. This may explain why our women assigned to sweeping of the membranes had a higher Bishop score on admission and a lower induction rate. *Multiple sweeping may therefore be more effective that single sweeping.*
>   This latter finding is in line with a recent randomised trial where women allocated to sweeping underwent a single sweep at 38 to 40 weeks of gestation and where no significant difference was found in the proportions of women who started labour spontaneously within seven days or before 41 weeks. *However, a single sweep performed post-term was effective in promoting spontaneous labour.* The timing of sweeping of the membranes may therefore be important. Future trials should aim at elucidating the optimum gestational age at which sweeping of the membranes should start.

So I think according to this study single sweeps before 41+0 are less effective than single sweeps after, but these authors seem to think that the pre-41 week sweeps may improve efficacy of the post-41 sweep. I'm curious if others draw the same conclusion.

Comment: I just want to say how disappointed I am in MedSci Stack Exchange for putting this question on hold. I found the information I needed here https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1471-0528.1998.tb09348.x and this could absolutely have been used as an answer to this question. I disagree with the assertion that it is a question that can only be answered by a doctor who can give personal medical advice. It is a question about probabilities related to average experiences. It goes without saying that further decision-making would involve a midwife or doctor! @bertieb

Comment: Please re-read the parts about "*appears* to be off-topic" and "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules". The question is *currently* phrased quite in the personal advice seeking style we *need to avoid* here. Feel free to read [ask] and [help] so that you may [edit] the question to get it re-opened.

Comment: thanks @LangLangC - I see what you mean. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thx for the edit. Can't wrap my head around it now for an edit myself, but "optimal" might lead to "opinions based" territory; better phrase that into "what choices" and consequences, likelihoods etc.

Comment: Understood, thanks @langlangc. Edited accordingly.

Comment: The wording is now rather confusing.  I would ask it more along the lines of "if a first membrane sweep is ineffective in promoting labor, is there evidence for doing a second membrane sweep? If so, at what interval?" and provide what you'd found so far in attempting to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Yes, the wording must be confusing, because that's not my question at all. My question is the reverse: Is there usefulness in the first membrane sweep (at 40 weeks) if a woman is going to get a membrane sweep at 41 weeks.

Comment: I'm confused. Is this question still on hold, or not?

Comment: It is still on hold. The community now has the opportunity to reopen it.

Comment: I have heavily reworked your question to make it clear, and to make it about what you actually want to know. Please do note that this academic question is in my eyes a valid one, but for you personally to draw conclusions, please discuss it with your midwife or doctor.

Comment: Thanks @Narusan. I've edited further. As I explained above, my question is not whether the 'second' membrane sweep is useful if the first fails. (It clearly is.) My question is whether the 40 week membrane sweep is useful at all in light of the opportunity to do a sweep at 41 weeks.

Comment: Is there any other reason in not getting the 40th sweep other than convenience? Because i don't see why not, patients will be required to do regular follow-ups anyway for post term pregnancy (around 2-3x a week) and your ob-gyne will be monitoring you by internal examination. So both procedures (internal exam and sweep) can be done simultaneously anyway during follow-up.

Comment: @kit sweeps are painful. Moreover, some would argue that minimising invasive procedures is a worthwhile goal in and of itself.

Comment: @the_scheining well that is a good point, I haven't done or encountered post-term sweeps yet. I'll ask my consultants next time for their opinion. But during labor, sweeps would be one of the least of your problems in terms of pain, uterine contractions are a lot worse as I was told by my patients.

Comment: @kit the sweep is not during labour; caregivers use sweeps to **increase the likelihood of** spontaneous labour.

Comment: @the_scheining you'll be surprised, sweeping is also done hasten the descent of the baby during labor, At least in our institution that is..

Comment: Ah thank you! To clarify, this question is about sweeps before labor begins.